# cron jobs fails run php script sometimes

Tags: php, cron

I am using php `file_get_contents` function to get some data from other websites.Also i use `cron jobs` to run that script automatically.The cronjobs works fine but sometimes fails to run.
this is my command in cron jobs (in cpanel):

`*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q public_html/include/imp.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

this command should repeat every 10 minutes.but not work sometimes even for 48 hours. it's ok when i run that php script manually.

thank you.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Check your log files.

Comment: where i can see log file ? thanks.

Comment: Do one thing. As you are using file_get_contents. Get small content from anyother url and see if this is working or not using cron. you can also use CURL to check the same. Tell us what happens then after.

Comment: If your hosting has the ability to send cron reports to emails, then set your email address and check what happens.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the cron was the problem, as your crontab looks correct.  The problem must be in imp.php - I bet if you look at /var/log/cron you'll see the script being called every 10 minutes

Comment: Mittul Chauhan : I have tried before.even curl.it's ok sometimes.but why it should not run for 48 hours ?
note:i have about 10 crons like this. may for many requests on server ?

Comment: joep1978 : this address does not exists in my host !

Comment: What flavour of Linux is your server running?

Comment: what is this error :
`/usr/local/.../jailshell: line 1: 105244 Killed                  /usr/bin/php -q public_html/include/imp.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: or this: 
`/usr/local/cpanel/.../jaishell: fork: Cannot allocate memory`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the script ran fine when the URL was visited directly, and would run sometimes, seemingly randomly. Turns out it was host server resource issue. Hostgator wont run a cron job when I'm connected via SSH with Putty on 2 computers.

From their help pages
"SSH access is limited to two simultaneous connections on Shared and Reseller plans.
Note: Any cron jobs configured will require one of these sessions to be available in order to run, since cron jobs run under the same shell as SSH."

When I close the SSH connection, the cron job immediately runs.

Maybe your host has a similar rule?